# Artifact already exists deployment error - how do I remove unnamed application artifacts?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, biztalk-deployment

I was developing a quick demonstration application for BizTalk 2010, and deployed the application without providing an application name in the project properties. It took me a minute to figure out why the application wasn't showing up in the BizTalk administration console, but once I did, I added a name to the application and tried redeploying. Now, I'm receiving an error telling me that one of the artifacts (a schema) is already deployed. I see that the schemas are present in the `< AllArtifacts >` collection in the administration console, but I'm at a loss for how I can remove them. I can't delete them directly in the console, and as the application had no name when I originally deployed it, it's not listed in the console, so I can't figure out how to remove it.

I can see some of the artifacts in the BizTalk directory on the server, but am reluctant to start deleting things by hand.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your project had no name when you deployed it to your local BizTalk, all artifacts will be deployed into the *default* BizTalk project, which is [usually BizTalk Application 1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa559168.aspx#BKMK_Step_by_step).

You can also check which application your artifacts were deployed to by looking at the `Application` column of the schemas under `<All Artifacts>` in the Admin Console.

You can then go into the project owning your schemas (e.g. `BizTalk Application 1`), under the schemas folder, right click on one of the schemas and select "remove". This will undeploy the whole assembly containing the schemas. You can do the same for any other assemblies e.g. containing Pipelines, Orchestrations etc, and then redeploy your project after setting a project name under the Deployment Properties tab in Visual Studio.

You may need to restart your host instances for the changes to take affect.

Comment: Huh. Interesting that they deploy to the default. Thanks.

Comment: You can also right click the assembly and select Move, and move it the the BizTalk Application you want it.  It will also move all the other DLL's that reference it.

Answer (score 0):

I've had to use BTSTask in the past, when things get really screwed up.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa561331.aspx